# How to get User Display name logged in in Python + Windows in AD Environment?

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, pywin32

I want to get the Full display name of user current logged in . I am on Active Directory login so usually I get username easily but I am looking for User's Display name.

path = os.path.join('..','Documents and Settings',getpass.getuser(),'Desktop')
os.getlogin()

This does not works as it gives username not display name.

Comment: @Vulpex Not duplicate, I am not asking for username, I am asking user's display name.

Comment: I quote: "I'm trying to get the user's full name. Not the login name," first sentence from the question linked.

Answer (score 2):

Is this what you want?

```
import ctypes

def get_display_name():
    GetUserNameEx = ctypes.windll.secur32.GetUserNameExW
    NameDisplay = 3

    size = ctypes.pointer(ctypes.c_ulong(0))
    GetUserNameEx(NameDisplay, None, size)

    nameBuffer = ctypes.create_unicode_buffer(size.contents.value)
    GetUserNameEx(NameDisplay, nameBuffer, size)
    return nameBuffer.value

print(get_display_name())
```

Second script

```
user_info = win32net.NetUserGetInfo(win32net.NetGetAnyDCName(),   win32api.GetUserName(), 2)
full_name = user_info["full_name"]
print(full_name)
```

Comment: Yes got this from another post, works.